# if fieldname is null then don't show

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to write a script where if a fieldname is null then it won't display a certain class. So...

```
  if (fieldName=null){
     document.style.display='block';
  }
  else {
     document.style.display='none';
  }

  <div class="tst"><sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="The Field" runat="server" /></div>
```

The question is this doesn't work. So what I am missing? So if the user enters text in the field, the field shows up, if the user doesn't then the div that contains the field needs to display:none;.

It is telling me that fieldName doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: That is a statement.  What is your question?

Comment: Why is this tagged under C#? I only see JS code here.

Comment: Because this is tied to a literal with a fieldname ID that is done with C#.

Comment: Post the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript when you compare two values you have to use == or ===.
What you are doing is you are assigning fieldname to null
So in your case I would change to this:

```
  if (fieldName===null){
    document.style.display='block';
  } 
  else {
    document.style.display='none';
  }
```

or even better:

```
 if (!fieldName){
    document.style.display='block';
  } 
  else {
    document.style.display='none';
  }
```